# Unfortunately app has stopped in adt emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-adt

I saw similar posts but none could help me out. I am making an android one to one voice chat app. However its getting stopped. I also set all the permissions in the manifest. Here is manifest code.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bridgecall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.bridgecall.CallActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.bridgecall.sender" >    
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Could i get any help in this matter?

Here is the log cat:

```
04-05 17:43:52.427: E/dalvikvm(1415): Could not find class 'javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat', referenced from method com.bridgecall.CallActivity.getAudioFormat
04-05 17:43:52.427: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 824 (Ljavax/sound/sampled/AudioFormat;) in Lcom/bridgecall/CallActivity;
04-05 17:43:52.427: D/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
04-05 17:43:52.537: I/dalvikvm(1415): Could not find method javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getMixerInfo, referenced from method com.bridgecall.CallActivity.callStart
04-05 17:43:52.537: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5343: Ljavax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem;.getMixerInfo ()[Ljavax/sound/sampled/Mixer$Info;
04-05 17:43:52.537: D/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0025
04-05 17:43:52.607: D/dalvikvm(1415): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x14dc at 0x09 in Lcom/bridgecall/CallActivity;.getAudioFormat
04-05 17:43:52.717: D/dalvikvm(1415): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x14e0 at 0x35 in Lcom/bridgecall/CallActivity;.callStart
04-05 17:43:52.717: D/dalvikvm(1415): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x14e0 at 0x61 in Lcom/bridgecall/CallActivity;.callStart
04-05 17:43:53.607: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 831 (Ljavax/sound/sampled/LineUnavailableException;)
04-05 17:43:53.607: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x10
04-05 17:43:53.617: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY:  rejected Lcom/bridgecall/sender;.<init> ()V
04-05 17:43:53.617: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0010
04-05 17:43:53.617: W/dalvikvm(1415): VFY:  rejected Lcom/bridgecall/sender;.<init> ()V
04-05 17:43:53.637: W/dalvikvm(1415): Verifier rejected class Lcom/bridgecall/sender;
04-05 17:43:53.637: W/dalvikvm(1415): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/bridgecall/sender;)
04-05 17:43:53.637: D/AndroidRuntime(1415): Shutting down VM
04-05 17:43:53.637: W/dalvikvm(1415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a66ba8)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): Process: com.bridgecall, PID: 1415
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415): java.lang.VerifyError: com/bridgecall/sender
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-05 17:43:53.677: E/AndroidRuntime(1415):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 17:43:57.027: I/Process(1415): Sending signal. PID: 1415 SIG: 9
```

and my CallActivity class

```
package com.bridgecall;



import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class CallActivity extends Activity {
    boolean stopCapture = false;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, sender.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.call, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void callStart()
     {
        try {
                        int port = 6039;
                        String host= "192.168.1.120";
            sock = new Socket(host, port);

            out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);

            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();

            Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
            captureThread.start();

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo1 = new DataLine.Info(
                    SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem
                    .getLine(dataLineInfo1);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine.start();



        } catch (Exception e) {


        }
    }

    class CaptureThread extends Thread {

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[1000];

        public void run() {
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            stopCapture = false;
            try {
                while (!stopCapture) {

                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                            tempBuffer.length);

                    out.write(tempBuffer);

                    if (cnt > 0) {

                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);

                    }
                }
                byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {


            }
        }
    }

    private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = false;
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
                bigEndian);
    }



}
```

and Sender class:

```
package com.bridgecall;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class sender {


    ServerSocket MyService;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    BufferedInputStream input;
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine;

    BufferedOutputStream out;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
    AudioFormat audioFormat;    

    SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;    
    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[1000];


    public sender() {
        try
        {
            mysender();
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void mysender() throws LineUnavailableException {

        try {    
            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo =  new DataLine.Info( SourceDataLine.class,audioFormat);
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine)
                AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
                sourceDataLine.start();
                int port= 6039;

        MyService = new ServerSocket(port);
        clientSocket = MyService.accept();
        captureAudio();
        input = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); 
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            while(input.read(tempBuffer)!=-1){          
                sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer,0,1000);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        } 

    }


     private AudioFormat getAudioFormat(){
            float sampleRate = 8000.0F;       
            int sampleSizeInBits = 8;          
            int channels = 1;           
            boolean signed = true;          
            boolean bigEndian = false;       
            return new AudioFormat(
                              sampleRate,
                              sampleSizeInBits,
                              channels,
                              signed,
                              bigEndian);
          }



    private void captureAudio() {
        try {

            Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();


            audioFormat = getAudioFormat();

            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                    TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);

            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);

            targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
            targetDataLine.start();

            Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
            captureThread.start();      
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    class CaptureThread extends Thread {

        byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[1000];

        public void run() {         
            try {
                while (true) {
                    int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                            tempBuffer.length);

                    out.write(tempBuffer);              
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

        public static void main(String args[]) {

        new sender();
           }
}
```

Comment: Look at the stacktrace in the logcat. This will usually tell you what's wrong. If you still can't figure it out, post the stacktrace here.

Comment: You have to show the code that is causing the exception and the exception.

Comment: I have posted the log cat.. however if it doesn't help i will put my src code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared your `sender` Activity in AndroidManifest, which is causing here `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Comment: still its the same thing.. I have edited the Logcat and my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat class not found

Include that class and app will start

Comment: That is already there in the jar Sir. That's the only reason I am able to import it. "import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;"

Comment: May I know which JAR for you used. you said it is crashing on emulator means working real android device?